# Are addon core and language part of addon recording?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I had recorded some of the actions in the system to a robot which includes some commands such as "mouse.click" and "keyboard", which comes under "addon core" but even when I ran that robot without including "addon core" to my robot it works perfectly. So, it is like when I am using "addon recording" I don't need to use any other addon?

Answer (score 0):

G1ANT.Addon.Core defines some very basic stuff, but in some special cases it might be not required. This is not the case here.

What happens is that this addon is already loaded (at the start of the Studio), and what you do by typing `addon xxx` assures that the script will run only if addon that you declare you use has been loaded. But - since Core and Language are always loaded (because they are embedded into Studio executable) - script could be ran without any of them declared in `addons` section.

But the Studio requires you to declare that you use those addons for some safety reasons, mainly version checking: addons embedded into Studio might be too outdated to run the script and Studio needs to detect that. There seems to be a minor bug, because the preparser checks just if there's any `addon` header, so you might declare you use `ui` and none of language/core, but on the list of loaded addons you will see ticked checkboxes next to language and core.

So the following configuration will work although it is not correct. It will be fixed in near future.
[image: Screenshot of wrong configuration with working script]